# How can I wrap these functions so their exceptions always get handled?

Tags: javascript, exception

I've looked through the threads here on this subject and can't find what I want.

I have a bunch of functions that return string and I want them to not return a string if the input is bad and I don't want the program to exit either AND I don't want to wrap every call in try / catch.

```
function foo(num){
  if(num > 5){
    throw SomeException("Input too big")
  }else{
    return "bar"+num
  }
}
```

I want to log an error like "6 is too big for foo", instead of exiting the program. But this will be kind of an api, so I don't want the user to have to try/catch every time they use 
one of these functions. This is a nodejs script.

this works, but is a awkward:

```
f = {
  command : function(cmd,arg){
              try {
                console.log(q[cmd](arg));
              }
              catch (e) {
                console.log("Error: " + e + " for " + cmd);
              }
            },
  foo : function(str){
              throw ("foo error");
        },
  foo2 : function(str){
           throw ("foo2 error");
         }

};
f.command("foo",2);
f.command("foo2",3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[[Edit]]** It's a nodeJS script. Then make the API asynchronous. We do not do synchronous operations in nodeJS. Please conserve the event loop.

You can also rework your API to be asynchronous

```
function foo(num, cb){
  if(num > 5){
    cb(SomeException("Input too big"));
  }else{
    cb(null, "bar"+num);
  }
}

foo(5, function(err, data) {
   ...
});
```

You can reference a public logger instance.

`MyLibrary.errorHandler = defaultErrorHandler() || config.errorHandler`

Then have the defaultErrorHandler be

```
function(error) {
    if (console && console.log) { console.log(error.message); }
    $("#errordiv").text(error.message);
}

function foo(num){
  if(num > 5){
    MyLibrary.errorHandler(new Exception("blargh"));
  }else{
    return "bar"+num;
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to make sure I'm asynchronous on these little functions?

Comment: @tladuke I assumed your example was overly trivial. If you want to do error handling nicely then this asynchronous pattern is nice. the whole `next` pattern is also nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating an API that others will use, and you want to signal that an error happened, well... throw an exception. If that exception doesn't get caught by the programmer using your API, that's their fault, not yours; on the other hand, if their code goes all wonky because your function does something really weird on an error, well... okay, that's still the other programmer's fault for not properly checking input coming into your API, but be a good citizen and help out their debugging by throwing that exception. They may dislike you for putting exceptions everywhere, but they'll *hate* you if your code just silently does really weird stuff instead of providing a good indication of what the error is.

I'd say log the error, too, but you're doing this in JavaScript, where there isn't any such facility.

And for the record, this is coming from a programmer who has used APIs that both do and do not throw exceptions on errors; the ones that do throw them are generally the ones I consider to be better-written.

Comment: I see what you're saying. This is to format strings to go to a piece of hardware. If the strings aren't formatted right (out of range), all that happens is the device doesn't respond. Not worth crashing the program, but I thought it would be nice to let them know why nothing happened when they sent a malformed command.

Comment: Exceptions let them know why their code failed in the loudest possible voice! ;-) It also lets them set up their own code to handle errors -- maybe they want to kill the program, maybe they want to log it and then move on, or maybe they have a way to programmatically fix the problem and make it work. Point being, why pigeon-hole them into one way of addressing an error condition when you can instead give them the tools to do it themselves?

Comment: try and catch can really slow a program down. It's fine for debugging but in production code it's not really wanted. You want to handle bad input in a different manner where possible.